# Mysql: Disk is full writing

Tags: mysql, centos

I'm having some problems with my mysql server lately, so I've decided to check the error logs:

---

```
[root@LSN-D1179 log]# tail -10 mysqld.log  
100325 19:30:03 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Table './lfe/actions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired  
100325 19:30:03 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Table './lfe/actions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired  
100325 19:30:18 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './omuz/ibf_task_logs.MYD' (Errcode: 122). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs  
100325 19:34:34 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './omuz/ibf_profile_portal_views.MYD' (Errcode: 122). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs  
100325 19:39:46 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './omuz/ibf_posts.TMD' (Errcode: 122). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs  
100325 19:40:18 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './omuz/ibf_task_logs.MYD' (Errcode: 122). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs  
100325 19:44:34 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing   './omuz/ibf_profile_portal_views.MYD' (Errcode: 122). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs  
100325 19:49:46 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './omuz/ibf_posts.TMD' (Errcode: 122). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
100325 19:50:18 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './omuz/ibf_task_logs.MYD' (Errcode: 122). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
100325 19:54:34 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './omuz/ibf_profile_portal_views.MYD' (Errcode: 122). Waiting for someone to free space... Retry in 60 secs
```

---

And here's is my df -h output

---

```
[root@LSN-D1179 log]# df -h  
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      143G  6.2G  129G   5% /  
/dev/sda1              99M   12M   83M  13% /boot  
tmpfs                 490M     0  490M   0% /dev/shm
```

---

As you can see, I have plenty of free space; so I couldn't figure out these "Disk is full" errors in mysqld.log.

Does anyone know what should I do to fix this?

Ugur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only two things I can come up with are:

1. Disk quota on the mysql user?
2. Filesystem corruption or hard disk failure.

Are you seeing any filesystem errors on boot or in your syslog?

Comment: It had something to do with disk quota's indeed. Although mysql user had unlimited quota, when I disabled user quotas altogether, problem was solved.